# Svelte Store Updates but UI doesn't react

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am running into an issue where I have confirmed the store is updated but the UI is not acting as I would expect. If I reload the page the updates appear so I think it is an issue with the way I am rendering it out. Anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong in this code?

The update is done on a button click that updates the occupiedBy attribute below:

Game.svelte

```
function attemptMove() {
if( attemptedCommand.hero !== null && 
    attemptedCommand.command !== '' && 
    attemptedCommand.targetX !== -1 && 
    attemptedCommand.targetY !== -1) {
      console.log(`Attempting to process ${attemptedCommand.command} of ${attemptedCommand.hero.hero.id} at [${attemptedCommand.targetX}, ${attemptedCommand.targetY}]`)
        if(attemptedCommand.command.toLowerCase() === 'move') {
          console.log($gameStore.map[attemptedCommand.targetX][attemptedCommand.targetY])
          gameStore.update((gameStore) => {
            const updatedMap = [...gameStore.map];
            updatedMap[attemptedCommand.targetX][attemptedCommand.targetY].occupiedBy = attemptedCommand.hero.hero;
            return {...gameStore, map: updatedMap };
          })
          console.log('Updated the map')
        }    

    }
}

<div class="game-area col-span-2 ml-36 mt-28">
    <div class="normal-map">
      {#each $gameStore.map as row, rowIndex }
      <div class="grid grid-cols-[96px,96px,96px,96px,96px,96px,96px,96px,96px,96px]" key={rowIndex}>
        {#each row as cell, cellIndex}
          <div class="cell scale-[3]" key={cellIndex} >
          <InteractiveMapTile background={cell.background} onClick={mapClick} {rowIndex} {cellIndex} character={cell.occupiedBy}/>
          </div>
        {/each}
      </div>
    {/each}
  </div>
  </div>
```

GmaeStore.js

```
// Create the writable store
export const gameStore = writable(initialData);

// Subscribe to changes in the store and update local storage
gameStore.subscribe((data) => {
  writeToLocalStorage(data);
});
```

Comment: What happens if you write

`gameStore.map[attemptedCommand.targetX][attemptedCommand.targetY].occupiedBy = attemptedCommand.hero.hero;`
`return gameStore;`